# How to get contact details in C# code , when new contact is created in Exchange Server 2013

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, exchange-server-2013

I need to **synchronize contacts in Exchange Server and Sugar CRM Application**.
10 users exists in my Exchange server , same users exists in Sugar CRM Application.
my task is to create service that, **if any User [ex:David] create new contact in Exchange server that contact should be created in same user account[David] in CRM Aplication through my service**.

How can i get newly added contact details in C# code [EWS Managed API] ?

Please share your ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to set up streaming notifications on David's contacts folder using the EWS Managed API. You'd use the same code as is included in [How to: Stream notifications about mailbox events by using EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458792%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). The difference is that you'd use [WellKnownFolderName.Contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.wellknownfoldername%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

Comment: i need to monitor all user accounts in my server, not only David's account. using streaming notifications is it possible for all accounts in server ?

Comment: Yes, it is available for all accounts. If you're dealing with large numbers, then you'll want to use impersonation to create the subscriptions to avoid getting throttled. This topic explains how to group your subscriptions and use impersonation: [How to: Maintain affinity between a group of subscriptions and the Mailbox server in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx).